# How to retrieve data from Dictionary using swift and store in a string type?

Tags: ios, string, swift, dictionary

I am creating iOS Application using swift.
XCODE version 6.3
I am storing NSData in NSString.This is the code for that.

```
var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Now the strData contains value like this.

```
**strData: Optional({"result":true,"user_id":2,"role_id":2,"msg":"Signed in successfully.”})**
```

I want to store the user_id and role_id in 2 separate strings.

For that First of all i changed NSString to normal String in Swift

```
var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        as String?
```

when we print strData output will be like this.

```
**strData: Optional("{\"result\":true,\"user_id\":2,\"role_id\":2,\"msg\":\"Signed in successfully.\"}”)**
```

In my view,the string is in the format of dictionary[Key value pair]

So i created a dictionary like this,

```
var lognInDetails = Dictionary<Int, String>()

 self.lognInDetails[1] = strData
```

And store string to the Dictionary.

this all working fine

The problem is i want to retrieve the value from dictionary based on the key.

For user_id key i want to store value 2.

I used this code,

```
self.userid = self.lognInDetails[ 1 , "user_id"] as Dictionary<Int, String>
```

Here userid is a String variable.
I am just a starter in swift.I am interested to learn more about both swift & objective-C.Thank For your Help.

Comment: Your data contains [JSON](http://json.org). Lookup `NSJSONSerialization`. There are *many* Q&A about JSON on SO.

Comment: Actually i am posting data to the server.you are right i am using NSJSONSerialization,here i pass a dictionary.According to my question here NSData is a success response from server,{result: true, user_id: 1, role_id: 1} this is the response from server if login is success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let userId = json?["user_id"]?.integerValue

Answer (score 1):

you can directly convert NSData to NSDictionary & then set Strings with values of them.To convert NSdata to NSDictionary use

```
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

Comment: Yaa i have done that,After that i want to fetch particular value based on a key. if self.userid = json["user_id"]
        {
            println("userid: \(self.userid)")
        }

Comment: then from dictionary u can get key value pair.

Comment: Yaa i understood.I am near to the answer.But some problem with syntax or something.                                                                                             if let name = json["user_id"] as AnyObject? as? String
        {
            println("userid: \(name)")
        }
I am trying different codes.But actual conversion is not yet occured.Here json denotes the dictionary name.

Comment: let name = json["user_id"] as String try this.

Comment: i already try that.I create error like this.AnyObject? is not converting to string

Comment: don't use AnyObject use as String

Comment: I dont use anyObject its a part of errror.Anyway i got it.I have posted the answer.